# Draw Multiple Circles horizontally android

Tags: android, android-layout, geometry, android-canvas, paint

How to draw multiple circles horizontally in android, with some filled color. 
And I want to change the color based on some server response.

Can anybody tell how to do this? I implemented like this to draw a circle.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new SampleView(this));

    }
    public class SampleView extends View
    {
        public SampleView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
             Paint mPaint = new Paint();
             mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
             mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
             canvas.drawCircle(30, 30, 10, mPaint);

        }
     }
```

I'm not able to get how to draw three more circles in the same line.
And how to change the color based on condition if I write like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose two option, either have multiple view, each having a single circle or draw multiple circle in a single view. I'd prefer the first option, but since your need may vary, so I am explaining both the option.

**Option 1:**
Have a class variable named as color, which can work as a property where you can change the color based on default color of the view. Run a loop outside the view, may be in onCreate() to increament x coordinate, which can be passed to the `drawCircle()` method.

**Option 2**
You can have an ArrayList of color for every circle. Run a loop in `onDraw()` method, which changes the color and increment the x coordinate based on loop counter.